# PHP's include not working properly

Tags: php, sql, include, modular

So recently I started a project where I need to load some files. In these files I have colors that come via SQL;

The Problem is, I can only include one color in a file where they'll be used. The first file to be included will work properly, but the second one will not.

The weirdest thing is that if I try to add some echo, all included files will echo it, but only the first one in the order of the import will actually work. It's kind of complicate to explain, but some code can help:

Portifolio.php (where I will use the colors)

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include_once ('php/db.php');
include_once ('php/colors/accent.php');
include_once ('php/colors/primary.php');
$page =
<<<HTML
// Long HTML code here
<nav class="$primarycolor">
// More code
<a class ="$accentcolor">
```

accent.php:

```
<?php
include ('../db.php');

$sql = "SELECT id, color FROM Colors WHERE id = 2";
$getcolor = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
echo "Accent.php included";

if ($getcolor->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $getcolor->fetch_assoc()) {
        $accentcolor = $row['color'];
    }
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

primary.php

```
<?php
include ('../db.php');

$sql = "SELECT id, color FROM Colors WHERE id = 1";
$getcolor = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
echo "Primary.php has been included";

if ($getcolor->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $getcolor->fetch_assoc()) {
        $primarycolor = $row['color'];
    }
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

db.php

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","mucap","pswd","webdata");
echo "DB included.";

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
    echo "Error: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

In this case:

No errors are gonna be displayed.

$accentcolor will work

$primarycolor will simply pretend it does not exists

All files will echo what they were told to.

I did a lot of research and figured out it could be something with file paths, but I dont think so: Here goes (part of) my file structure:

[image]

I cant do [$DOCUMENT_ROOT] as this is not supposed to have a fixed path, long explanation. 
What should I do?

Comment: because primary.php and accent.php both have  `include ('../db.php');`

Comment: So how do I solve that?

Comment: `include_once()`

Comment: That is what I am doing.

Comment: no its not, on db.php in accent.php and primary.php

Comment: I'm not including the DB anymore in accent and primary. Still it's only loading the first one @nogad

Comment: remove `include ('../db.php');` from other scripts, when u load other scripts to main file in your case portfolio.php you already have a connection that will be used on accent.php or primary.php

Comment: I did that @Mario, nothing changed.

Comment: `mysqli_close($conn);` remove this, your closing the connection in the first include, then try to reuse it in the 2nd include

Comment: @nogad Please transform it in answer so I can accept it. this is the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing your statement with this:

```
if ($getcolor) {
    while($row = $getcolor->fetch_assoc()) {
        $primarycolor = $row['color'];
    }
} else{
     echo"no results in row";
}
```

The simple if check is possible because the results of a search return "FALSE" if there's no data in the results.
The else statement is required just for verification purposes.

If you only expect 1 result, you can do "LIMIT 1" as well as eliminate the while statement.
If you don't want the script to run at all, you should use require_once, not include_once